# Unable to remove the video component from render tree even after the parent component is killed

Tags: javascript, c#, video.js, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to create a video component with Blazor. I'm using the video.js library for video-related features. The code is in repo https://github.com/VenkateshSrini/BlazorComponents.
Now when I run the code for the first time, The counter page comes up. It has a button called player which when clicked launches the videplayer.razor. This page has a video tag. It displays the vide and I also have a timer on the page that periodically updates the remaining time and duration in localStorage of browser. This is achieved through the Javascript bridge. Then when I again click back the counter page it smoothly transition without error. Now when I repeat the same operation the next time I get a weird error. I'm unable to proceed further I do not understand what is happening. The error is as below

> blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null
> at e (http://localhost:5000/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:6918)
> at Object.e [as removeLogicalChild] (http://localhost:5000/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:6890)
> at e.applyEdits (http://localhost:5000/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:13649)
> at e.updateComponent (http://localhost:5000/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:12880)
> at Object.t.renderBatch (http://localhost:5000/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:1704)
> at Object.window.Blazor._internal.renderBatch (http://localhost:5000/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:34784)
> at _mono_wasm_invoke_js_unmarshalled (http://localhost:5000/_framework/wasm/dotnet.3.2.0.js:1:172099)
> at wasm_invoke_iiiiii (http://localhost:5000/_framework/wasm/dotnet.wasm:wasm-function[3160]:0x9b33d)
> at icall_trampoline_dispatch (http://localhost:5000/_framework/wasm/dotnet.wasm:wasm-function[5777]:0xfe711)
> at mono_wasm_interp_to_native_trampoline (http://localhost:5000/_framework/wasm/dotnet.wasm:wasm-function[4607]:0xca81d)
> Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null
> at e (http://localhost:5000/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:6918)
> at Object.e [as removeLogicalChild] (http://localhost:5000/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:6890)
> at e.applyEdits (http://localhost:5000/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:13649)
> at e.updateComponent (http://localhost:5000/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:12880)
> at Object.t.renderBatch (http://localhost:5000/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:1704)
> at Object.window.Blazor._internal.renderBatch (http://localhost:5000/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:34784)
> at _mono_wasm_invoke_js_unmarshalled (http://localhost:5000/_framework/wasm/dotnet.3.2.0.js:1:172099)
> at wasm_invoke_iiiiii (http://localhost:5000/_framework/wasm/dotnet.wasm:wasm-function[3160]:0x9b33d)
> at icall_trampoline_dispatch (http://localhost:5000/_framework/wasm/dotnet.wasm:wasm-function[5777]:0xfe711)
> at mono_wasm_interp_to_native_trampoline (http://localhost:5000/_framework/wasm/dotnet.wasm:wasm-function[4607]:0xca81d)
> at Microsoft.JSInterop.WebAssembly.WebAssemblyJSRuntime.InvokeUnmarshalled[T0,T1,T2,TResult] (System.String identifier, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2) <0x2cd31a0 + 0x00046> in :0
> at Microsoft.JSInterop.WebAssembly.WebAssemblyJSRuntime.InvokeUnmarshalled[T0,T1,TResult] (System.String identifier, T0 arg0, T1 arg1) <0x2cd30c0 + 0x00014> in :0
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer.UpdateDisplayAsync (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderBatch& batch) <0x2cd2fc8 + 0x0001e> in :0
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue () <0x2b81948 + 0x000f2> in :0

I have created a vide to replicate the steps using the code provided in the Github url. The repo steps vidoe is available at https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoG_S7xXx9nDhpMyVM9FqmtFP1ci6w?e=FfYs4y

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue. I had change the calls to InvokeVoidasync and all the passing of parameter was handled using sessionstorage/localstorage. I was using a timer on the Blazor page. So I had implemented a Dispose method using IDisposable. But to perform the cleanup activity of removing the video control I again had to call Javascript. I could not do that in Dispose because Dispose was a sync method. The GetAwaiter().GetResult(), So implemented IAsyncDisposable. Then I used the disposeasync and dispose method. These things fixed the issue.